# Secure channels without web-of-trust or CA

Tags: man-in-the-middle

I was reading about Impagliazzo's five worlds and I have some questions about cryptomania and minicrypt:
What is difference between them? I cannot find one?
How does cryptomaniac MitM protection work in SSL/TSL? Does it still need some level of trust?